# Robots.txt exclude certain urls and include others

Tags: robots.txt

I have a robots text file which needs to mass exclude certain urls, currently setup as so

```
Disallow: /somestring

Disallow: /*/somestring
```

However, some of my URLs generated by users are coming back like:

```
/somestring-something-else
```

I would like to `Allow:` this type of URL. In other words, if there are no other characters after a pattern match like `/somestring` or `/*/somestring` exclude, if there are other characters, include.

Is there a way around this, or a robots directive appropriate in this index?

Comment: Have you tested this using Google Webmaster Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there are no other characters after a pattern match like `/somestring` or `/*/somestring` exclude, if there are other characters, include.

You can use `$` to designate the end of the URL.

```
Disallow: /somestring$
Disallow: /*/somestring$
```

If there are other characters in the URL after `somestring`, then they will not match and will therefore be allowed by default.

As with the "wildcard" `*`, this is not part of the original robots.txt standard, but is supported by all the major search engines.